# no row with the given identifier exists hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

Hi i am working on Entity Mapping by using @ManyToOne Annotation.

below is my entities with manytoone association between them

student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class student{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UserID")
    private String userid;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name = "userrole1", referencedColumnName = "VALUE"),
       @JoinColumn(name = "userrole2", referencedColumnName = "DESCRIPTION")

    })
    private studentdetails1 userrole1;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name = "userrole1", referencedColumnName = "VALUE",insertable=false, updatable=false),
       @JoinColumn(name = "userrole2", referencedColumnName = "DESCRIPTION", insertable=false, updatable=false)

    })
    private studentdetails2 userrole2;

//setters and getters 
//constructor

}
```

studentdetails1.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details1")
public class studentdetails1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

   //setters and getters 
   //constructor
}
```

studentdetails2.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details2")
public class studentdetails2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

   //setters and getters 
   //constructor
}
```

appmain.java

```
public static void main()
{

//session configuration
     StudentDetails1  sd1 = new StudentDetails1();
            sd1.setValue("abc");
            sd1.setDescription("abcdef");
        StudentDetails2  sd2 = new StudentDetails2();
            sd2.setValue("abcd");
            sd2.setDescription("abcdefd");

            Student student1 = new Student();
            student1.setUserid("1");
            student1.setUserrole1(sd1);
            student1.setUserrole2(sd2);

            Student student2 = new Student();
            student2.setUserid("2");
            student2.setUserrole1(sd1);
            student2.setUserrole2(sd2);
        session.save(student1 );
        session.save(student2 );

        Student con = (Student ) session.get(Student .class,
                        String.valueOf(1));
        System.out.println(con.getUserid());
    }
```

getting error for below line

```
student con = (student ) session.get(student .class,
                    String.valueOf(1));
```

I am using EAGER FETCH TYPE,when I save the data I am able save and retrieve the data using SESSION.GET but when I comment the session.save methods, even though there are values in the database for these tables I am getting below error

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.studentdetails2e#studentdetails2(value=1, description=null)]

at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$2.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:447)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:233)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1028)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:623)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:140)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:898)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:773)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1933)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3270)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:997)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:990)
at com.softsol.test.ActvDayRangeRlTest.AccountValid(ActvDayRangeRlTest.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I tried to solve this but it showing same error.

please suggest me how to solve this

Comment: Show the correct code, your code says you are having LAZY mapping between entities then where you are setting EAGER? Also show the code where you are trying to get the entity and the complete stacktrace of the exception. Also the code says `student.setuserid("1");` but there is no reference called `student` please provide correct information.

Comment: sorry.please find the updated fetchType="EAGER".

Comment: interesting, as per your previous question you do have only userrole, so now you added two columns to your table to maintain the relationship? So did my answer to that question has fixed your issue.

Comment: yes its working fine for lazy fetch type but getting error for eager fetch type, please suggest me for this case.

Comment: ok, then please mark it as answered for previous one. Coming back to this, exactly at what line of code you are getting exception, please add complete stacktrace to your question.

Comment: if code in `appmain.java` is giving exception then show us the correct code to reproduce the issue, as per reference variables in your given code the program will give compile time errors not this hibernate exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From stacktrace it says that hibernate loaded `Student` entity and when it is trying to load the `StudentDetail` entity then it is not able to find a record in database table matching that composite primary key.

Based on the stacktrace I guess the issue is this:

You have a record in `Student` table with primary key value as `1` and foreign key values as `userrole1=1` and `userrole2=null`. So when you tried to get a record with id as `1` from `Student` table using hibernate and as the fetching strategy is `EAGER` then it tried to find a record in `Student_Detail` table with composite primary key as `VALUE=1` and `DESCRIPTION=null` but hibernate was not able to find it and thrown an exception saying:

```
No row with the given identifier exists: [com.studentdetails2e#studentdetails(value=1, description=null)]
```

So check your DB data in Student table with primary key as `1`, the foreign key mapping should be incorrect. Again I guess at DB side you do not have any foreign key relationship between tables because if that is the case then DB will not allow incorrect FKeys.

**Update:**

When you use `LAZY` for mapping and try to fetch a record for `Student` then hibernate will assign proxy for the collection elements i.e StudentDetail. When you try to access this collection element then only hibernate will hit the database to get a record for StiudentDetail.

In case of `EAGER` loading, when you try to fetch a record of `Student` then there itself hibernate will try to get the mapping StudentDetail entity, due to this you are getting exception while using `EAGER` but not for `LAZY` fetching.

Comment: we should not have any relationship on DB side(that's our requirement we should map them from Entity side only).Even though we are able to fetch data from DB when we use Lazy Fetch type,why don't we get data using fetch type EAGER only.pls suggest us

Comment: based on the stacktrace you can guess why you got the error for EAGER but not for LAZY, I have updated my answer with details, please check.

Comment: thanks for the info but is there any way to get the data using EAGER with same mapping or its not possible.

Comment: If this is the case,we should get null values for both the child objects, why we are getting only for studentdetails2 why not for studentdetails1(observed from stack trace)

Comment: as I said in my answer first check your database tables and verify if the records are correct. If the data itself is incorrect then expecting hibernate wont fix it for you.

Comment: Also I forgot to tell you, based on Student entity you have mapping with StudentDetails1 and StudentDetails2 but both are mapped with same foreign key names `userrole1, userrole2`, this is not correct way of working with hibernate. Please understand the mappings correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had all annotated correctly but in the database, there was a lacking FK between `table A fk---> table B`, so there was a row in table `A` with a value of `b` that didn't exist in table B (this error should have been detected in the migration).

The exception could mislead your attention from the real problem, it "can't find the row xxx' so it can't recover the `Entity X`, but the problem could be any other Entity as an attribute of X, like `X#user` or `X#person`